# Kotlin Set Global Variable in Global Class

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm new to Kotlin. 
And I need a help that I can't understand to java and kotlin.

For Java I made it. But for kotlin I can't 
The thing is, 
I create a Global kotlin class 
public class Global : Application()

In MainFest I declared that 
 android:name=".Global"

and in Global Class I declared a variable:

```
public class Global : Application() {
    open var homeAPIResponse: String = "defaultValue"
}
```

When I set to this global variable any value, it's won't save and when I fetch the value always it's showing default value. I can't understand the java type getter and setter methods in kotlin. Please help me.

I tried that:

```
global = Global()
global.homeAPIResponse  = "2nd Text"

Log.d("testingTag", "Testing modified response >>>> " + global.homeAPIResponse)
```

In log it's always showing the defaultvalue.

=========================================================================
Guys, my purpose is to save some value globally that, after moves one activity to another, the value will not erase.

Please help me with proper described example cause I searched a lot on stack overflow. and coudn't get it.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe try like this:

```
public class Global : Application() {
    companion object {
        @JvmField
        var homeAPIResponse: String = "defaultValue"
    }
}
```

In other activity:

```
Global.homeAPIResponse = "new value"
```

Comment: How to call homeAPIResponse ?
g = Global ()
g.homeAPIResponse is not working !

Comment: How to call homeAPIResponse ?
g = Global ()
g.homeAPIResponse is not working !

Comment: @Sanchyan Chakraborty Just Global.homeAPIResponse

Comment: Thanks Man. Thank You.
It works
by using this 
 val compObj = Global.Companion
  compObj.homeAPIResponse  --> this is using for getter and setter. 
Thanks Again

Comment: Thanks Man. Thank You.
It works
by using this 
 val compObj = Global.Companion
  compObj.homeAPIResponse  --> this is using for getter and setter. 
Thanks Again

Comment: @Sanchyan Chakraborty Ok, or add: import app.Global.Companion.homeAPIResponse and everywhere in the code use homeAPIResponse = ...

Answer (score 3):

It seems you are creating the `Global()` application manually; you shouldn't be doing this.

The one `Application` class is created automatically when your app starts.

You want it as a global variable? Do the answer suggested by having:

```
companion object {
    var globalVariable = "initial value"
}
```

Put that inside the `Global()` class. Don't make a new `Global()` instance manually. Instead in your activity simply call `Global.globalVariable = "your new value"`

Also, you can make it what kotlin calls a "Top Level Variable". Declare it **above** the Global class declaration, as follows:

```
var yourGlobalVariable = "default text"

class Global : Application () {

 // etc.
```

This can be used anywhere. Start typing it in your application (without `Global`, just on its own), and it will import.

**edit**

If your purpose is to have a global variable that persists between activities, doing it using a class (even the application class) really isn't advisable.

Have you considered `SharedPreferences`?

Get with

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).getString("key to access with", "default value")
```

And store with

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).edit().putString("key to access with", "your new value").apply()
```

Comment: Can you please explain why global variable isn't advisable, what could be the negative consequences?

Comment: Sure. It's to do with memory management. The behaviour of the application class and activities are a bit of an unknown in terms of memory cleanup and garbage collection. There is simply no guarantee that those global variables will persist. The application class could be recreated. We don't have control over this.

Comment: A very good solution to this would be using android's `ViewModel` class and sharing it between activities. In fact this would be the pattern recommended by Google. https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel

Comment: But... this then will make an app without this architecture in place more complex. It's definitely a jump in difficulty from Global variables!

Comment: My pleasure. If anything in the answer was helpful an upvote is always appreciated 

Answer (score 1):

Do you know that you can just create your global variale in a simple kt file like this:

`var homeAPIResponse = "defaultValue"`

With this you can update it anywhere you want like this:

`homeAPIResponse = "2nd Text"`

Hope it helps you

Comment: It working on same activity. But when the activity changes, the initilized value "defaultValue" is showing on next activity. It need to save the 2nd Text in that Global Variable, but it won't.

Comment: @Armel Gildas Fagbedji This variant also works for me.

Comment: @alexrnov Happy to know that it helps you

Answer (score 0):

you can also do this way.

```
const val homeAPIResponse: String = "defaultValue"
```

when you want to use it   just type homeAPIResponse anywhere

consts are compile time constants. Meaning that their value has to be assigned during compile time, unlike vals, where it can be done at runtime.

This means, that consts can never be assigned to a function or any class constructor, but only to a String or primitive.

Answer (score 0):

For this I use following options in Kotlin:

- Observer pattern.
- Singleton object.

The observer pattern may take more time to implement, but in the end you will benefit from this. There is lots of flexibility, anyone can subscribe to the data and and class can inject new data. A good example is at: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5WIS-GydJmw&t=620s
Big advantage of the observer is that the notifiers can immediately process the incoming data, e.g. put on screen.

Another option is to make an object instead of a class, this acts as a singleton. I like to use this for databases, inside the object I will use lateinit var so the objects are only created when used. Don't use singletons when the data is only used at a few places.

Here the example:

```
object SqlData {
    init {
    }    
    public lateinit var sql_item: SqlItem
    public lateinit var sql_alamat: SqlAlamat
    public lateinit var sql_floor_table: SqlFloorTable
```

Code to access the singleton:

```
override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return SqlData.sql_floor_table.getSize()
    }
```